# How do i find the critical points of this function without using a graph?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-system

I am trying to find the critical points of the equation:

$$f(x,y) = x\ln y + x^2 -4x -5y +8 .$$

Found the partial derivative in terms of $x$ and got $\ln y +2x -4$ and for  $y$ I got $\frac{x}{y} -5$.

I equated the two to $0$:

$$\ln y +2x -4 = 0 , $$

$$\frac{x}{y}  -5 = 0 .$$

How do I find $x$ and $y$?

Comment: In general, your best bet for non-linear systems of equations are numerical methods. I don't know of any analytic solution to $\ln y = g(y)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please edit your question with formatting using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it helps make your question more legible.

Comment: There are fast numerical techniques. See [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NSolve%5B%7BLog%5By%5D+%2B+2+x+-+4+%3D%3D+0+%26%26+x%2Fy+-+5+%3D%3D+0%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+y%7D%5D)

Answer (score 0):

From the second equation, $y=\frac x5$. Plug in the first to obtain
$$2x+\log(x)=4+\log(5)$$ that is to say
$$2x+\log(2x)=4+\log(10)\implies x=\frac{1}{2} W\left(10 e^4\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.
Numerically,
$$x \sim 2.37270 \implies y\sim 0.47454$$

If you do not want to (or cannot) use Lambert function, just use graphing or inpection; this shows the the solution is $\in (2,3)$. Make one iteration of Newton method :  $$x_0=2\implies x_1=2+\frac{2}{5} \log \left(\frac{5}{2}\right) \sim 2.36652$$
$$x_0=3\implies x_1=\frac{3}{7} \left(5+\log \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\right) \sim 2.36178$$